# secureTextEntry not working

Tags: ios, swift, text, uitextfield, swift3

I am trying to make a password entry from a text field that ONLY be create programatically, NOT through interface builder, but when I try to set secureTextEntry to "true" however I just get a "Value of type 'UITextField' has no member 'secureTextEntry'"

```
myTextField.secureTextEntry = true
```

As I can't use the interface builder to turn secure text on, how can I get around this. All other questions relating to this seem to only be it not always working, not not exisisting.

Comment: "Edit -> Convert -> To current Swift syntax" auto converts that to `myTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true`.

Comment: Thank you, this has been such a headache!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.secureTextEntry` has been changed to `.isSecureTextEntry` in swift 3